# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double while trying to parse a pdf page to image using pdfrenderer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to convert a pdf file page into an image using `pdfrenderer` ,But I'm  getting the below error on compilation. How to rectify this?
 my code

```
File file = new File("image.png");
        System.out.println("Inside readFromFiles!!!!!");
        String fname = new File(getFilesDir(), "Android Tutorial.pdf")
                .getAbsolutePath();
        FileChannel fChannel = new FileInputStream(fname).getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = fChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,
                fChannel.size());
        System.out.println("Buffer" + buffer);
        PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(buffer);
        PDFPage page = pdfFile.getPage(0);
        System.out.println("page" + page);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int) page.getBBox().getWidth(),
                (int) page.getBBox().getHeight());
        System.out.println("Rect" + rect);
        Image img = page.getImage(rect.width, rect.height, rect, null);
        System.out.println("img" + img);
        RenderedImage rImage = (RenderedImage) img;
        ImageIO.write(rImage, "png", file);
        System.out.println("Image Created");
```

The errors I get are:

```
    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-2210:56:16.834:ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float
    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.parseRect(PDFFile.java:1523)
    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.createPage(PDFFile.java:1419)
    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.getPage(PDFFile.java:1330)

    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.getPage(PDFFile.java:1301)

    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at com.example.PdfLibraryActivity.PdfLibraryActivity.readFromFiles(PdfLibraryActivity.java:137)

    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at com.example.PdfLibraryActivity.PdfLibraryActivity.onCreate(PdfLibraryActivity.java:42)

    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

    03-22 10:56:16.834: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9572):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897775/using-awt-with-android

Answer (score 4):

```
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float
```

**Java awt is not supported by Android.** You have to use Android related class and make changes on your code accordingly to it.

You can use [awt-android-compat](http://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/) for that. It facilitate AWT rendering on the Android platform.