# Am I missing a java class?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was trying to include referenced library when this error showed up on a line that apparently made use of the Rectangle2D class. For some reason it seems I'm missing that class.

```
The type java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

After some Google searches I figured out I had to simply add Rectangle2D to as a reference, but I can't find it anywhere.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Do I need to download it separately? Or am I no searching good enough? Where is that file located?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double while trying to parse a pdf page to image using pdfrenderer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816991/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-awt-geom-rectangle2ddouble-while-trying-to)

Comment: Try [this](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~awl03/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/miro/browser/trunk/gcc/libjava/classpath/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.java?rev=36) one.

Answer (score 3):

`java.awt` refers to Java's [Abstract Window Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) which is not included in the Android framework.
Try referencing [this library](http://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I am not referencing that library. But the library I'm using is. And I can't get to the source.

Comment: So if I where to add that library, it would still reference sun.awt.geom.Rectangle2D

Comment: You can find Rectangle2D.java under svn/branches/alpha-demo/src/and/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.java
Its package name is `and.awt.geom` but you can try and change it to satisfy that library you're using

Answer (score 0):

try 
import java.awt.geom.RectangularShape