# Is Rectangle a built-in class

Tags: java, android

I am writing a java code in eclipse . But here eclipse show me that "Rectangle is not a build in java class " . What can I do ? The error is pictured in the following image .

[image]

The main problem is that I have written the following line in android in eclipse . But eclipse show me error . What can I do to resolve this error ?

```
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int) page.getBBox().getWidth(),
                                     (int) page.getBBox().getHeight());
```

I have imported the necessary packages to support this "Rectangle" class . But the conditions of situation is same as before .

```
import java.awt.Rectangle ;
```

Comment: Copy paste your code rather than posting a screenshot. Besides, it hurts my eyes to read such small text.

Comment: You are trying to use Java AWT with Android. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897775/using-awt-with-android

Comment: Sorry for your problems . @adarshr

Comment: I have come to know that android doesnt support "java.awt.Rectangle"

Comment: @SultanAhmedSagor Can you paste the code? It is not just "my" problem!

Comment: I have done editing . You can review it . @adarshr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import `java.awt.Rectangle` so that the Java compiler knows which Rectangle class you're referring to.

You can let Eclipse create your import statements by right clicking on the editor view and left clicking on Source -> Organize Imports.

Comment: to expand on this answer, it's "built-in" in that it's part of the standard java api found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ but it's not part of the "default" package that doesn't require import statements the way the Math and Language packages are. eclipse SHOULD be giving you a little red error button with the option that says something like "add import statement"

Comment: Look at the screenshot more closely: he's using Android

Comment: I have imported the necessary package . But eclipse show me error . Why ?

Comment: I have come to know that android does not support "java.awt.Rectangle"  ? Is it right ?

Comment: I didn't notice the Android tag.  There's android.graphics.Rect.